# Multinomial Logistic Regression in R: varying label set

Tags: r, logistic, multinomial-distribution, multinomial-logit

I have a relatively large data set of 9M rows that is almost 1GB in size. The data looks like:

```
t   e    p    acs    acc    v    correct_p
t1  e11  p11  acs11  acc11  v11  0
t1  e12  p12  acs12  acc12  v12  1
t1  e13  p13  acs13  acc13  v13  0
...
t2  e21  p21  acs21  acc21  v21  0
t2  e22  p22  acs22  acc22  v22  0
t2  e23  p23  acs23  acc23  v23  1
t2  e24  p24  acs24  acc24  v24  0
...
t3  e31  p31  acs31  acc31  v31  1
t3  e32  p32  acs32  acc32  v32  0
```

My questions are:

1. Is it feasible to train/iterate a multinomial logistic regression model on my local installation of R for the data set above? I have access to a computing cluster, but I'd have to use the `ml`Python library or Scala, both of which I am less familiar with.
2. If the answer to the previous is yes, then I am concerned about my `labels`. There are 3.1M distinct labels (the `p` column). For each `t`, I would like to calculate the probability for each of the labels `p` possible only for that `t`. So `t1` can only be labeled with `p11`, `p12` or `p13` and `t3` can only be labeled with `p31` or `p32`. The features would be `acs`, `acc` and `v`. Is this possible? I've only ever seen cases where there is a small set of labels available for all observations.